# Python json_dumps in a single line without multiple {

Tags: python

I am exporting mysql table to a json file with

```
d = collections.OrderedDict()
d[i["parameter_name"]]=i["parameter_value"]#parameter_name
json_data.append(d)
result_json=json.dumps(json_data)
```

Currently the file is separate JSON records {}:
[{"Param1": "10.0000"}, {"Param2": "20.0000"}]

It should be one long JSON record in the format (only one set of {}):
[{"Param1": "10.0000", "Param2": "20.0000" ]

Any idea/ suggestion how to achieve this?

Comment: Is this code part of a loop?

Comment: You need to create the dictionary once, before the loop. Inside the loop you add to the dictionary. Then you dump it at the end. There's no need for the list.

Comment: init the `result_json` as a empty dict and update with `json_data` item: `for i in json.dumps(json_data): result_json.update(i)`

Comment: Please post more of the code for context.

Answer (score 0):

i'd do a dict comprehension

```
result_**string** = json.dumps( { key: value for key, value in *your_itereator* } )
```

string because you are using dumps

or maybe it looks like this, assuming you got the stuff in a dict called data (because you are using keys in your example)

```
{ x: data.get(x) for x in parameter_list }
```

or lazier

```
{ x: data.get(x) for x in data.keys() if "param" in x.lower() }
```

or to order them:

```
{ (z:=f"Param{x}"): data.get( z, "") for x in range(max_param) }
```